# Adding Counter to Tower of Hanoi Android Andengine APP

Tags: android, andengine, towers-of-hanoi

I made a Towers of Hanoi game using android with AndEngine. I'm wondering if anyone knows how to use the "scene.attachChild" as the one who displays the moves. It only displays once i move a ring and it stacks(text covering the last text) once i keep on moving the rings.

I want it to appear as "Moves: " when I start the game and it adds +1 per move and it won't stack. Can anyone help me? Much help would be appreciated.

Here is the code for the counter:

```
if (stack != null && tower !=null && stack.size() == 0) {
        ring.setPosition(tower.getX() + tower.getWidth()/2 - ring.getWidth()/2, tower.getY() + tower.getHeight() - ring.getHeight());
        count = count + 1;
```

Here is the code for the text display:

```
private void isCount(){
    Font main_font = FontFactory.create(this.getFontManager(), this.getTextureManager(), 256, 256, BitmapTextureFormat.RGBA_8888, TextureOptions.BILINEAR_PREMULTIPLYALPHA, Typeface.DEFAULT, 60, true, Color.BLACK_ABGR_PACKED_INT);
    main_font.load();

    Text CountText = new Text(0, 0, main_font, "Moves" + count , this.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
    CountText.setPosition(CAMERA_WIDTH/2 - CountText.getWidth()/2, CAMERA_HEIGHT/2 - CountText.getHeight()/2);
    scene.attachChild(CountText);

}
```

Comment: check the post for changing the number of moves count.You must not load resouces everytime. You have to load only once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
change text constructor of 'count text' as follows:

Text countText = new Text(0, 0, main_font, "Moves:" + movesCount ,10,  this.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
            countText.setPosition(CAMERA_WIDTH - countText.getWidth(), 10);
            scene.attachChild(countText);
It has to use to indicate minimum characters
```

You can get tutorials from following link:
[check here](http://www.matim-dev.com/)

Comment: I tried to change the text as you instructed but the application force closed instead. 

  Text countText = new Text(0, 0, main_font, "Moves:" + movesCount ,10,  this.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
         countText.setPosition(0,0);
         scene.attachChild(countText);

The counter of the movements is

if (ring.collidesWith(mTower1) && (mStack1.size() == 0 || ring.getmWeight() < ((Ring) mStack1.peek()).getmWeight())) {
            stack = mStack1;
            tower = mTower1;
            movesCount++;
            countText.setText("Moves: "+ movesCount);

until the the last "else if"

Comment: The following code is having resolved text bug and implemented logic for not repeating  moves for same tower

Comment: Never mind. I managed to fix it. I forgot that countText was already assigned at the upper part of the code. Thanks again Rama!

 countText = new Text(0, 0, main_font, "Moves:" + movesCount ,10,  this.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
         countText.setPosition(0,0);
         scene.attachChild(countText);

Answer (score 0):

```
package org.farook.towerofhanoi;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Stack;

import org.andengine.engine.camera.Camera;
import org.andengine.engine.options.EngineOptions;
import org.andengine.engine.options.ScreenOrientation;
import org.andengine.engine.options.resolutionpolicy.RatioResolutionPolicy;
import org.andengine.entity.scene.Scene;
import org.andengine.entity.sprite.Sprite;
import org.andengine.entity.text.Text;
import org.andengine.input.touch.TouchEvent;
import org.andengine.opengl.font.Font;
import org.andengine.opengl.font.FontFactory;
import org.andengine.opengl.texture.ITexture;
import org.andengine.opengl.texture.TextureOptions;
import org.andengine.opengl.texture.atlas.bitmap.BitmapTextureAtlas;
import org.andengine.opengl.texture.atlas.bitmap.BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory;
import org.andengine.opengl.texture.bitmap.BitmapTexture;
import org.andengine.opengl.texture.bitmap.BitmapTextureFormat;
import org.andengine.opengl.texture.region.ITextureRegion;
import org.andengine.opengl.texture.region.TextureRegionFactory;
import org.andengine.ui.activity.SimpleBaseGameActivity;
import org.andengine.util.adt.io.in.IInputStreamOpener;
import org.andengine.util.color.Color;
import org.andengine.util.debug.Debug;

import android.graphics.Typeface;

public class TowerOfHanoiActivity extends SimpleBaseGameActivity {
    private static int CAMERA_WIDTH = 800;
    private static int CAMERA_HEIGHT = 480;
    private ITextureRegion mBackgroundTextureRegion, mTowerTextureRegion, mRing1, mRing2, mRing3;
    private Sprite mTower1, mTower2, mTower3;
    private Stack<Ring> mStack1, mStack2, mStack3;
      private ITexture main_font_texture;
      Text countText;
      Font main_font;
      int movesCount;
    Scene scene;
    @Override
    public EngineOptions onCreateEngineOptions() {
        final Camera camera = new Camera(0, 0, CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT);
        return new EngineOptions(true, ScreenOrientation.LANDSCAPE_FIXED, new RatioResolutionPolicy(CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT), camera);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreateResources() {
        try {


            main_font = FontFactory.create(this.getFontManager(), this.getTextureManager(), 256, 256, BitmapTextureFormat.RGBA_8888, TextureOptions.BILINEAR_PREMULTIPLYALPHA, Typeface.DEFAULT, 60, true, Color.BLACK_ABGR_PACKED_INT);
            main_font.load();


             BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.setAssetBasePath("gfx/");
             main_font_texture = new BitmapTextureAtlas(getTextureManager(), 256, 256, TextureOptions.BILINEAR_PREMULTIPLYALPHA);

            // 1 - Set up bitmap textures
            ITexture backgroundTexture = new BitmapTexture(this.getTextureManager(), new IInputStreamOpener() {
                @Override
                public InputStream open() throws IOException {
                    return getAssets().open("gfx/background.png");
                }
            });
            ITexture towerTexture = new BitmapTexture(this.getTextureManager(), new IInputStreamOpener() {
                @Override
                public InputStream open() throws IOException {
                    return getAssets().open("gfx/tower.png");
                }
            });
            ITexture ring1 = new BitmapTexture(this.getTextureManager(), new IInputStreamOpener() {
                @Override
                public InputStream open() throws IOException {
                    return getAssets().open("gfx/ring1.png");
                }
            });
            ITexture ring2 = new BitmapTexture(this.getTextureManager(), new IInputStreamOpener() {
                @Override
                public InputStream open() throws IOException {
                    return getAssets().open("gfx/ring2.png");
                }
            });
            ITexture ring3 = new BitmapTexture(this.getTextureManager(), new IInputStreamOpener() {
                @Override
                public InputStream open() throws IOException {
                    return getAssets().open("gfx/ring3.png");
                }
            });
            // 2 - Load bitmap textures into VRAM
            backgroundTexture.load();
            towerTexture.load();
            ring1.load();
            ring2.load();
            ring3.load();
            // 3 - Set up texture regions
            this.mBackgroundTextureRegion = TextureRegionFactory.extractFromTexture(backgroundTexture);
            this.mTowerTextureRegion = TextureRegionFactory.extractFromTexture(towerTexture);
            this.mRing1 = TextureRegionFactory.extractFromTexture(ring1);
            this.mRing2 = TextureRegionFactory.extractFromTexture(ring2);
            this.mRing3 = TextureRegionFactory.extractFromTexture(ring3);
            // 4 - Create the stacks
            this.mStack1 = new Stack<Ring>();
            this.mStack2 = new Stack<Ring>();
            this.mStack3 = new Stack<Ring>();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Debug.e(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected Scene onCreateScene() {
        // 1 - Create new scene
        scene = new Scene();
        Sprite backgroundSprite = new Sprite(0, 0, this.mBackgroundTextureRegion, getVertexBufferObjectManager());
        scene.attachChild(backgroundSprite);

        // 2 - Add the towers
        mTower1 = new Sprite(192, 63, this.mTowerTextureRegion, getVertexBufferObjectManager());
        mTower2 = new Sprite(400, 63, this.mTowerTextureRegion, getVertexBufferObjectManager());
        mTower3 = new Sprite(604, 63, this.mTowerTextureRegion, getVertexBufferObjectManager());
        scene.attachChild(mTower1);
        scene.attachChild(mTower2);
        scene.attachChild(mTower3);

        // 3 - Create the rings
        Ring ring1 = new Ring(1, 139, 174, this.mRing1, getVertexBufferObjectManager()) {
            @Override
            public boolean onAreaTouched(TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent, float pTouchAreaLocalX, float pTouchAreaLocalY) {
                if (((Ring) this.getmStack().peek()).getmWeight() != this.getmWeight())
                    return false;
                this.setPosition(pSceneTouchEvent.getX() - this.getWidth() / 2, pSceneTouchEvent.getY() - this.getHeight() / 2);
                if (pSceneTouchEvent.getAction() == TouchEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    checkForCollisionsWithTowers(this);
                }
                return true;
            }
        };
        Ring ring2 = new Ring(2, 118, 212, this.mRing2, getVertexBufferObjectManager()) {
            @Override
            public boolean onAreaTouched(TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent, float pTouchAreaLocalX, float pTouchAreaLocalY) {
                if (((Ring) this.getmStack().peek()).getmWeight() != this.getmWeight())
                    return false;
                this.setPosition(pSceneTouchEvent.getX() - this.getWidth() / 2, pSceneTouchEvent.getY() - this.getHeight() / 2);
                if (pSceneTouchEvent.getAction() == TouchEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    checkForCollisionsWithTowers(this);
                }
                return true;
            }
        };
        Ring ring3 = new Ring(3, 97, 255, this.mRing3, getVertexBufferObjectManager()) {
            @Override
            public boolean onAreaTouched(TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent, float pTouchAreaLocalX, float pTouchAreaLocalY) {
                if (((Ring) this.getmStack().peek()).getmWeight() != this.getmWeight())
                    return false;
                this.setPosition(pSceneTouchEvent.getX() - this.getWidth() / 2, pSceneTouchEvent.getY() - this.getHeight() / 2);
                if (pSceneTouchEvent.getAction() == TouchEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    checkForCollisionsWithTowers(this);
                }
                return true;
            }
        };
        scene.attachChild(ring1);
        scene.attachChild(ring2);
        scene.attachChild(ring3);
        // 4 - Add all rings to stack one
        this.mStack1.add(ring3);
        this.mStack1.add(ring2);
        this.mStack1.add(ring1);
        // 5 - Initialize starting position for each ring
        ring1.setmStack(mStack1);
        ring2.setmStack(mStack1);
        ring3.setmStack(mStack1);
        ring1.setmTower(mTower1);
        ring2.setmTower(mTower1);
        ring3.setmTower(mTower1);
        // 6 - Add touch handlers
        scene.registerTouchArea(ring1);
        scene.registerTouchArea(ring2);
        scene.registerTouchArea(ring3);
        scene.setTouchAreaBindingOnActionDownEnabled(true);

        countText = new Text(0, 0, main_font, "Moves:" + movesCount , this.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
        countText.setPosition(CAMERA_WIDTH - countText.getWidth(), 10);
        scene.attachChild(countText);

        setTheMovesCount();
        return scene;
    }

        private void setTheMovesCount() {


    }

        private void checkForCollisionsWithTowers(Ring ring) {
            Stack<Ring> stack = null;
            Sprite tower = null;
            if (ring.collidesWith(mTower1) && (mStack1.size() == 0 || ring.getmWeight() < ((Ring) mStack1.peek()).getmWeight())) {
                stack = mStack1;
                tower = mTower1;
            } else if (ring.collidesWith(mTower2) && (mStack2.size() == 0 || ring.getmWeight() < ((Ring) mStack2.peek()).getmWeight())) {
                stack = mStack2;
                tower = mTower2;
            } else if (ring.collidesWith(mTower3) && (mStack3.size() == 0 || ring.getmWeight() < ((Ring) mStack3.peek()).getmWeight())) {
                stack = mStack3;
                tower = mTower3;
            } else {
                stack = ring.getmStack();
                tower = ring.getmTower();
            }
            ring.getmStack().remove(ring);
            if (stack != null && tower !=null && stack.size() == 0) {
                ring.setPosition(tower.getX() + tower.getWidth()/2 - ring.getWidth()/2, tower.getY() + tower.getHeight() - ring.getHeight());
            } else if (stack != null && tower !=null && stack.size() > 0) {
                ring.setPosition(tower.getX() + tower.getWidth()/2 - ring.getWidth()/2, ((Ring) stack.peek()).getY() - ring.getHeight());
            }
            stack.add(ring);
            ring.setmStack(stack);
            ring.setmTower(tower);

            movesCount++;
            if(countText != null){
                  countText.setText("Moves:"+ movesCount);
            }

            isGameOver();
        }

        private void isGameOver() {
            if(mStack3.size() == 3){

                 Text gameOverText = new Text(0, 0, main_font, "GameOver", this.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
                 gameOverText.setPosition(CAMERA_WIDTH/2 - gameOverText.getWidth()/2, CAMERA_HEIGHT/2 - gameOverText.getHeight()/2);
                 scene.attachChild(gameOverText);

                 scene.clearTouchAreas();
           }

            }
}
```

Comment: Thanks again Rama! The code works! I edited the coordinates of the "Moves: " text to appear on the left instead of the right though. Thanks! Do you have a site for tutorials about AndEngine? @Rama

There seems to be a problem with the counting of moves, if i click the ring and just let it stay where it was first located, the moves adds one count. How do I fix this? It also crashes once it reaches 10 counts.

Comment: i will check that problem and get back to you

Comment: I managed to fix the problem regarding the counting of the rings. the problem left here is the one where it crashes once the count reaches to 10.

Answer (score 0):

```
package org.farook.towerofhanoi;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Stack;

import org.andengine.engine.camera.Camera;
import org.andengine.engine.options.EngineOptions;
import org.andengine.engine.options.ScreenOrientation;
import org.andengine.engine.options.resolutionpolicy.RatioResolutionPolicy;
import org.andengine.entity.scene.Scene;
import org.andengine.entity.sprite.Sprite;
import org.andengine.entity.text.Text;
import org.andengine.input.touch.TouchEvent;
import org.andengine.opengl.font.Font;
import org.andengine.opengl.font.FontFactory;
import org.andengine.opengl.texture.ITexture;
import org.andengine.opengl.texture.TextureOptions;
import org.andengine.opengl.texture.atlas.bitmap.BitmapTextureAtlas;
import org.andengine.opengl.texture.atlas.bitmap.BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory;
import org.andengine.opengl.texture.bitmap.BitmapTexture;
import org.andengine.opengl.texture.bitmap.BitmapTextureFormat;
import org.andengine.opengl.texture.region.ITextureRegion;
import org.andengine.opengl.texture.region.TextureRegionFactory;
import org.andengine.ui.activity.SimpleBaseGameActivity;
import org.andengine.util.adt.io.in.IInputStreamOpener;
import org.andengine.util.color.Color;
import org.andengine.util.debug.Debug;

import android.graphics.Typeface;

public class TowerOfHanoiActivity extends SimpleBaseGameActivity {
    private static int CAMERA_WIDTH = 800;
    private static int CAMERA_HEIGHT = 480;
    private ITextureRegion mBackgroundTextureRegion, mTowerTextureRegion, mRing1, mRing2, mRing3;
    private Sprite mTower1, mTower2, mTower3;
    private Stack<Ring> mStack1, mStack2, mStack3;
      Text countText;
      Font main_font;
      int movesCount;
    Scene scene;
    @Override
    public EngineOptions onCreateEngineOptions() {
        final Camera camera = new Camera(0, 0, CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT);
        return new EngineOptions(true, ScreenOrientation.LANDSCAPE_FIXED, new RatioResolutionPolicy(CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT), camera);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreateResources() {
        try {


            main_font = FontFactory.create(this.getFontManager(), this.getTextureManager(), 256, 256, BitmapTextureFormat.RGBA_8888, TextureOptions.BILINEAR_PREMULTIPLYALPHA, Typeface.DEFAULT, 60, true, Color.BLACK_ABGR_PACKED_INT);
            main_font.load();


             BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.setAssetBasePath("gfx/");

            // 1 - Set up bitmap textures
            ITexture backgroundTexture = new BitmapTexture(this.getTextureManager(), new IInputStreamOpener() {
                @Override
                public InputStream open() throws IOException {
                    return getAssets().open("gfx/background.png");
                }
            });
            ITexture towerTexture = new BitmapTexture(this.getTextureManager(), new IInputStreamOpener() {
                @Override
                public InputStream open() throws IOException {
                    return getAssets().open("gfx/tower.png");
                }
            });
            ITexture ring1 = new BitmapTexture(this.getTextureManager(), new IInputStreamOpener() {
                @Override
                public InputStream open() throws IOException {
                    return getAssets().open("gfx/ring1.png");
                }
            });
            ITexture ring2 = new BitmapTexture(this.getTextureManager(), new IInputStreamOpener() {
                @Override
                public InputStream open() throws IOException {
                    return getAssets().open("gfx/ring2.png");
                }
            });
            ITexture ring3 = new BitmapTexture(this.getTextureManager(), new IInputStreamOpener() {
                @Override
                public InputStream open() throws IOException {
                    return getAssets().open("gfx/ring3.png");
                }
            });
            // 2 - Load bitmap textures into VRAM
            backgroundTexture.load();
            towerTexture.load();
            ring1.load();
            ring2.load();
            ring3.load();
            // 3 - Set up texture regions
            this.mBackgroundTextureRegion = TextureRegionFactory.extractFromTexture(backgroundTexture);
            this.mTowerTextureRegion = TextureRegionFactory.extractFromTexture(towerTexture);
            this.mRing1 = TextureRegionFactory.extractFromTexture(ring1);
            this.mRing2 = TextureRegionFactory.extractFromTexture(ring2);
            this.mRing3 = TextureRegionFactory.extractFromTexture(ring3);
            // 4 - Create the stacks
            this.mStack1 = new Stack<Ring>();
            this.mStack2 = new Stack<Ring>();
            this.mStack3 = new Stack<Ring>();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Debug.e(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected Scene onCreateScene() {
        // 1 - Create new scene
        scene = new Scene();
        Sprite backgroundSprite = new Sprite(0, 0, this.mBackgroundTextureRegion, getVertexBufferObjectManager());
        scene.attachChild(backgroundSprite);

        // 2 - Add the towers
        mTower1 = new Sprite(192, 63, this.mTowerTextureRegion, getVertexBufferObjectManager());
        mTower2 = new Sprite(400, 63, this.mTowerTextureRegion, getVertexBufferObjectManager());
        mTower3 = new Sprite(604, 63, this.mTowerTextureRegion, getVertexBufferObjectManager());

        mTower1.setTag(1);
        mTower2.setTag(2);
        mTower3.setTag(3);

        scene.attachChild(mTower1);
        scene.attachChild(mTower2);
        scene.attachChild(mTower3);

        // 3 - Create the rings
        Ring ring1 = new Ring(1, 139, 174, this.mRing1, getVertexBufferObjectManager()) {
            @Override
            public boolean onAreaTouched(TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent, float pTouchAreaLocalX, float pTouchAreaLocalY) {
                if (((Ring) this.getmStack().peek()).getmWeight() != this.getmWeight())
                    return false;
                this.setPosition(pSceneTouchEvent.getX() - this.getWidth() / 2, pSceneTouchEvent.getY() - this.getHeight() / 2);
                if (pSceneTouchEvent.getAction() == TouchEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    checkForCollisionsWithTowers(this);
                }
                return true;
            }
        };
        Ring ring2 = new Ring(2, 118, 212, this.mRing2, getVertexBufferObjectManager()) {
            @Override
            public boolean onAreaTouched(TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent, float pTouchAreaLocalX, float pTouchAreaLocalY) {
                if (((Ring) this.getmStack().peek()).getmWeight() != this.getmWeight())
                    return false;
                this.setPosition(pSceneTouchEvent.getX() - this.getWidth() / 2, pSceneTouchEvent.getY() - this.getHeight() / 2);
                if (pSceneTouchEvent.getAction() == TouchEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    checkForCollisionsWithTowers(this);
                }
                return true;
            }
        };
        Ring ring3 = new Ring(3, 97, 255, this.mRing3, getVertexBufferObjectManager()) {
            @Override
            public boolean onAreaTouched(TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent, float pTouchAreaLocalX, float pTouchAreaLocalY) {
                if (((Ring) this.getmStack().peek()).getmWeight() != this.getmWeight())
                    return false;
                this.setPosition(pSceneTouchEvent.getX() - this.getWidth() / 2, pSceneTouchEvent.getY() - this.getHeight() / 2);
                if (pSceneTouchEvent.getAction() == TouchEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    checkForCollisionsWithTowers(this);
                }
                return true;
            }
        };
        scene.attachChild(ring1);
        scene.attachChild(ring2);
        scene.attachChild(ring3);
        // 4 - Add all rings to stack one
        this.mStack1.add(ring3);
        this.mStack1.add(ring2);
        this.mStack1.add(ring1);
        // 5 - Initialize starting position for each ring
        ring1.setmStack(mStack1);
        ring2.setmStack(mStack1);
        ring3.setmStack(mStack1);
        ring1.setmTower(mTower1);
        ring2.setmTower(mTower1);
        ring3.setmTower(mTower1);
        // 6 - Add touch handlers
        scene.registerTouchArea(ring1);
        scene.registerTouchArea(ring2);
        scene.registerTouchArea(ring3);
        scene.setTouchAreaBindingOnActionDownEnabled(true);

        countText = new Text(0, 0, main_font, "Moves:" + movesCount ,10,  this.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
        countText.setPosition(CAMERA_WIDTH - countText.getWidth(), 10);
        scene.attachChild(countText);

        setTheMovesCount();
        return scene;
    }

        private void setTheMovesCount() {


    }

        private void checkForCollisionsWithTowers(Ring ring) {
            Stack<Ring> stack = null;
            Sprite tower = null;

            boolean isRingUpdated = false;
            if (ring.collidesWith(mTower1) && (mStack1.size() == 0 || ring.getmWeight() < ((Ring) mStack1.peek()).getmWeight())) {
                stack = mStack1;
                tower = mTower1;

               isRingUpdated = checkIsRingUpdated(ring, mTower1);

            } else if (ring.collidesWith(mTower2) && (mStack2.size() == 0 || ring.getmWeight() < ((Ring) mStack2.peek()).getmWeight())) {
                stack = mStack2;
                tower = mTower2;

                isRingUpdated =  checkIsRingUpdated(ring, mTower2);
            } else if (ring.collidesWith(mTower3) && (mStack3.size() == 0 || ring.getmWeight() < ((Ring) mStack3.peek()).getmWeight())) {
                stack = mStack3;
                tower = mTower3;

                isRingUpdated =   checkIsRingUpdated(ring, mTower3);
            } else {
                stack = ring.getmStack();
                tower = ring.getmTower();
            }
            ring.getmStack().remove(ring);
            if (stack != null && tower !=null && stack.size() == 0) {
                ring.setPosition(tower.getX() + tower.getWidth()/2 - ring.getWidth()/2, tower.getY() + tower.getHeight() - ring.getHeight());
            } else if (stack != null && tower !=null && stack.size() > 0) {
                ring.setPosition(tower.getX() + tower.getWidth()/2 - ring.getWidth()/2, ((Ring) stack.peek()).getY() - ring.getHeight());
            }
            stack.add(ring);
            ring.setmStack(stack);
            ring.setmTower(tower);


            if(isRingUpdated){
                movesCount++;
                if(countText != null){
                    countText.setText("Moves:"+ movesCount);
                }

            }

            isGameOver();
        }

        private boolean checkIsRingUpdated(Ring ring, Sprite mTower) { 
            if(ring.getmTower().getTag() != mTower.getTag()){
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        private void isGameOver() {
            if(mStack3.size() == 3){

                 Text gameOverText = new Text(0, 0, main_font, "GameOver", this.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
                 gameOverText.setPosition(CAMERA_WIDTH/2 - gameOverText.getWidth()/2, CAMERA_HEIGHT/2 - gameOverText.getHeight()/2);
                 scene.attachChild(gameOverText);

                 scene.clearTouchAreas();
           }

            }
}
```